# Is there a way to somehow control the scroll position of scrollable components (e.g. ScrollView) declaratively?

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

i.e. by using a variable: state, Animated value, Reanimated value, whatever...

We can use imperative scrolling (like scrollToOffset etc.), but what about a declarative one? I mean how can we control the offset by dragging some other view using a pan responder for example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.